# Bootstrap collapse not working properly...Bootstrap right side white space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

1. First Question

Bootstrap collapse not working when i check responsive...but when i resize my browser it works but still there is a prblem i dont want it to collapsed next to  navbar brand...it must be under it
[collapseImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CPAL.jpg)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Font Awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Flex Slider/flexslider.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand pull-left">Lorem</a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[whiteSpaceImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M06bf.png)

1. Second questioin is about white space on right side

   ```
               <!-- SLIDER -->
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
               <div class="flexslider" id="slider">
                 <ul class="slides">
                   <li id="slide1"><video id="myVideo" src="./videos/myVideo.mp4" style="width:100%;"></video></li>      
                   <li id="slide2"><img src="Images/Slider Images/image1.jpg"></li>
                   <li id="slide3"><img src="Images/Slider Images/image2.jpg"></li>
                   <li id="slide4"><img src="Images/Slider Images/"></li>
                   <li id="slide4"><img src="Images/Slider Images/"></li>      
                 </ul>
               </div>
           </div>  
       </div>  
   </div>
   ```

   /*-----  NAVIGATION   ----*/

   ```
   html{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
           overflow-x: hidden; 
       }
       #mainNav{
           background:transparent;
           border: none;
           overflow:hidden !important; 
       }
       .navbar-default a{
           color: white !important;
           transition: color 0.5s;
           font-weight: bolder;
       }
       .navbar-default a:hover{
           color: black !important;
       }
       #slider{
           border: none;
           margin: 0px !important; 
       }
   /* ----  HEADER -----*/

   #slider img{
           height: 100vh;
           width: 100%;'
   }
   .col-sm-12{
           padding-left:0 !important;
           padding-right:0 !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: jsfiddle.net, put the code in the relevant sections (Add Bootstrap CSS and JS on the left under 'external resources'), hit save, then edit your question with the link.

Comment: its about 2 hours im trying to do it....i cant